# Homologous surfaces in three-manifolds

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

Let M be a 3-manifold. Let $S$ and $T$ be properly embedded surfaces in $M$ such that $[S] = [T] \in H_2(M, N(\partial S)) $. Is it true that we can isotope $\partial S$ so that it coincides with $\partial T$?

Comment: Every knot in $S^3$ bounds a properly embedded surface, right?  If so, then you get an easy counterexample by using any two non-isotopic knots.

Comment: By properly embedded I mean that $\partial S \subset \partial M$. So a properly embedded knot in $S^3$ would have empty boundary.

Comment: I see:  I interpreted "proper" in the sense of "preimage of compact is compact".  Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: cutting out an open tubular neighborhood of a knot embedding yields the property of being properly embedded for the seifert surfaces. Hence you would have to carefully construct this space sucht that the surfaces do not intersect (eg. by taking connected sum of spheres) and you get $\partial S \subset \partial M$. The real reson why we can't use what you said above, is that we look at different homology groups, since they are relative to different non isotopic knots in $\partial M$.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general this is impossible. For instance, $\partial S$ and $\partial T$ can have different numbers of components. Take $S$ and add to it a (relatively) null-homologous disjoint properly embedded surface $S'$ with boundary whose boundary is in $N(\partial S)$. Then $T=S+S'$ is your example. If you and a connected example, do the embedded connected sum (within $M$) of the surfaces $S$ and $S'$. The result will be your surface $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Take your favourite properly embedded compressible surface, and compress it. You have changed the Euler characteristic, but not the homology class.